# SQL limit join/concatenation result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, for-xml-path

Table `Master`:

```
----------------------
| Name      | ID     |
----------------------
| A         | 1      |
| B         | 2      |
| C         | 3      |
----------------------
```

Table `Detail`:

```
----------------------
| masterID  | det     |
----------------------
| 1         | 21      |
| 1         | 31      |
| 1         | 442     |
| 1         | 76      |
| 2         | 1       |
| 2         | 90      |
| 3         | 48      |
| 3         | 56      |
| 3         | 109     |
----------------------
```

Requested result:
Do a join and concatenation but limit the number of concatenated values to X (here 2) and if it's more then create a new row. for example the expected result from above will be:

```
----------------------
| Name      | dets   |
----------------------
| A         | 21, 31 |
| A         | 442, 76|
| B         | 1, 90  |
| C         | 48, 56 |
| C         | 109    |
----------------------
```

Using the below code I can get all the result concatenated however I need help about how to limit the number of records concatenated :

```
SELECT Master.Name, 
STUFF((
SELECT ','+Detail.det
FROM Detail
WHERE Master.ID = Detail.masterID
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
,1,2,'')
FROM Master
```

Also created the SQLFiddle for it : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1b69/1/0

Comment: Which dbms? (Some non-standard functionality used here...)

Comment: it's SQL server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()` and integer division to create a key that increments for every other row. Do that in a CTE and use the CTE in the main query and the for xml query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/890a4d/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Master
(
  Name varchar(10),
  ID int
);

create table Detail
(
  masterID int,
  det varchar(10)
);

go

insert into Master values
('A', 1),
('B', 2),
('C', 3);

insert into Detail values
(1, 21 ),
(1, 31 ),
(1, 442),
(1, 76 ),
(2, 1  ),
(2, 90 ),
(3, 48 ),
(3, 56 ),
(3, 109);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with C as
(
  select M.Name,
         D.masterID,
         D.det,
         (row_number() over(partition by D.masterID order by D.det) - 1) / 2 as rn
  from dbo.Detail as D
    inner join dbo.Master as M
      on D.masterID = M.ID
)
select C.Name,
       stuff ((select ', ' + D.det
               from C as D
               where C.masterID = D.masterID and
                     C.rn = D.rn
               for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
from C
group by C.masterID,
         C.Name,
         C.rn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/890a4d/1/0)**:

```
| Name |         |
|------|---------|
|    A |  21, 31 |
|    A | 442, 76 |
|    B |   1, 90 |
|    C | 109, 48 |
|    C |      56 |
```

Answer (score 0):

`FOR XML` applies to the structure of the result set.  I'm pretty sure you can do this just by using `TOP 2` in the subquery.

However, you might find that conditional aggregation is faster:

```
select m.name,
       (max(case when seqnum = 1 then cast(id as varchar(255)) else '' end) +
        max(case when seqnum = 2 then ', ' + cast(id as varchar(255)) else '' end) 
       ) as ids
from master m join
     (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by m.masterId order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from detail d
     ) d
     on m.id = d.masterid
where seqnum <= 2
group by name;
```

Or, because you don't seem to care about the particular ids, use the min and max:

```
select m.name,
       (case when minid = maxid then cast(minid as varchar(255))
             else cast(minid as varchar(255)) + ', ' + cast(maxid as varchar(255))
        end) as ids
from master m join
     (select d.masterid, min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid
      from detail d
      group by d.masterid
     ) d
     on m.id = d.masterid;
```

Comment: In case there is more than 2 for example for Name = A I need to see another record in the result. You can see this for both A and C in my result table. Top 2 will only return the first row and ignore the rest. both queries you suggested are also doing the same

Comment: @Asha . . . Ahh, I see that now.